# Does NoneType class inherit object class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the below class hierarchy,

[image]
[image]

Does class `NoneType` inherits class `object`?

*Note : python 3.5*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in both Python2 and Python3:

```
>>> type(None)
<class 'NoneType'>
>>> type(None).mro()
[<class 'NoneType'>, <class 'object'>]
>>> issubclass(type(None), object)
True
>>> isinstance(None, object)
True
```

Note that in Python2, the *only* classes that are not subclasses of `object` are old-style classes. However, instances of such classes are still instances of `object`:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     pass
... 
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo
<__main__.Foo instance at 0x7f2a33474bd8>
>>> type(foo)
<type 'instance'>
>>> foo.__class__
<class __main__.Foo at 0x7f2a33468668>
>>> Foo.mro()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: class Foo has no attribute 'mro'
>>> issubclass(Foo, object)
False
>>> isinstance(foo, object)
True
>>> type(foo).mro()
[<type 'instance'>, <type 'object'>]
>>> issubclass(type(foo), object)
True
```

Edit: I suspect some things might be different for Python < 2.6 and possibly for types implemented in C.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) function can tell you this.

```
>>> isinstance(None, object)
True
```

Comment: Technically, instance checking is not the same thing as subclass checking, which is also not the same thing as mro checking.

Comment: @o11c  `str.__bases__` gives `object`. But `NoneType.__bases__` does not give `object`. Is `__bases__` property relevant to check subclass?

Comment: @overexchange `type(None).__bases__ == (object,)` for me on python2.7 and python3.5

Answer (score 1):

Yes, though I can only test with version 3.4

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, May  5 2015, 17:58:45)
[GCC 4.9.2] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> None.__class__
<class 'NoneType'>
>>> issubclass(None.__class__, object)
True
```